# IPv6 DHCP PD reply going to FORWARD rule in iptables firewall?

Tags: linux, dhcp, ipv6

On my Fedora 34 Linux firewall/router box I noticed

- that IPV6 DHCP PD requests are sent out fine.
- that IPV6 DHCP PD replies do arrive on the wire
- that the firewall kernel for some reason sends the DHCP PD reply in the FORWARD rule even though dhclient is *local*
- that addresses in the packets were correct, match with DHCP-server and local firewall.

Details can be found at [redhat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1956209).

We have a ppp interface:

```
# ip -6 a s dev ppp0
20: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1492 qdisc cbq state UNKNOWN group default qlen 3
inet6 fe80::c5d5:e942:39c7:7eb7 peer    fe80::9ecc:83ff:fec6:e7e5/128 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

We have dhclient listening at ppp0:

```
# lsof -p 4066992 -n
COMMAND      PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
dhclient 4066992 root  cwd    DIR              254,0     4096    40961 /root
dhclient 4066992 root  rtd    DIR              254,0     4096        2 /
dhclient 4066992 root  txt    REG              254,2  2018144   141553 /usr/sbin/dhclient
dhclient 4066992 root  mem    REG              254,2    53728    22104 /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.33.so
dhclient 4066992 root  mem    REG              254,2  1913544    21939 /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so
dhclient 4066992 root  mem    REG              254,2    32696    30196 /usr/lib64/libcap-ng.so.0.0.0
dhclient 4066992 root  mem    REG              254,2   842360    30776 /usr/lib64/ld-2.33.so
dhclient 4066992 root    0u   CHR              136,4      0t0        7 /dev/pts/4 (deleted)
dhclient 4066992 root    1u   CHR              136,4      0t0        7 /dev/pts/4 (deleted)
dhclient 4066992 root    2u   CHR              136,4      0t0        7 /dev/pts/4 (deleted)
dhclient 4066992 root    3u  unix 0x000000001f2593f7      0t0 16525445 type=DGRAM (UNCONNECTED)
dhclient 4066992 root    4w   REG              254,4       64      251 /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient6.leases
dhclient 4066992 root    5w  FIFO                0,8      0t0 16525446 pipe
dhclient 4066992 root    6u  IPv6           16524541      0t0      UDP [fe80::c5d5:e942:39c7:7eb7]:dhcpv6-client
```

That appears to be all correct.

Then the packets that come in:

```
# tcpdump -i ppp0 -vn port 546
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: listening on ppp0, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked v1), snapshot length 262144 bytes
06:53:09.236781 IP6 (flowlabel 0x7f0d8, hlim 1, next-header UDP (17) payload length: 60) fe80::c5d5:e942:39c7:7eb7.dhcpv6-client > ff02::1:2.dhcpv6-server: [udp sum ok] dhcp6 solicit (xid=b68ba1 (client-ID hwaddr/time type 1 time 394565497 004063f60200) (option-request DNS-server DNS-search-list) (elapsed-time 65535) (IA_PD IAID:0 T1:3600 T2:5400))
06:53:09.469530 IP6 (class 0xc0, hlim 64, next-header UDP (17) payload length: 141) fe80::9ecc:83ff:fec6:e7e5.dhcpv6-server > fe80::c5d5:e942:39c7:7eb7.dhcpv6-client: [udp sum ok] dhcp6 advertise (xid=b68ba1 (client-ID hwaddr/time type 1 time 394565497 004063f60200) (server-ID vid 0000058339633a63) (IA_PD IAID:0 T1:3600 T2:5760 (IA_PD-prefix 2001:981:a812::/48 pltime:7200 vltime:7200)) (DNS-server 2001:888:0:6::66 2001:888:0:9::99))
06:53:09.469756 IP6 (class 0xc0, hlim 63, next-header UDP (17) payload length: 141) fe80::9ecc:83ff:fec6:e7e5.dhcpv6-server > fe80::c5d5:e942:39c7:7eb7.dhcpv6-client: [udp sum ok] dhcp6 advertise (xid=b68ba1 (client-ID hwaddr/time type 1 time 394565497 004063f60200) (server-ID vid 0000058339633a63) (IA_PD IAID:0 T1:3600 T2:5760 (IA_PD-prefix 2001:981:a812::/48 pltime:7200 vltime:7200)) (DNS-server 2001:888:0:6::66 2001:888:0:9::99))
^C
```

Appear to be addressed correctly, to the dhclient interface.

So why doesn't dhclient receive?

I did test without an active firewall: no change.
I simplified routing, etc but no change.

It is not the problem from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702489/response-udp-packets-not-arriving-regardless-of-right-ip-and-port-after-sending as the dhcp-server can be contacted due to the routes present.

Where do I look to find out why a DHCP reply packet with a PD in it does not arrive locally?

Please post.
Udo

Comment: Why do you say the reply is sent to a FORWARD rule?

Comment: An UDPv6_Dropped message is logged in the FORWARD rule unless I open up the FORWARD, but then the problem has already occurred.

Comment: I don't see your iptables rules? I don't see a packet capture? Where are all your details?

Comment: Some details can be found at [redhat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1956209). As the issue also persists without firewall I did not post firewall details yet; it's an ADSL4Linux derivative.